# SQlite Index on 2 number fields?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have a table which I access by 2 int fields all the time so want an index to help. There is no writes ever. The int fields are not unique.

What is the most optimal index?

```
Table
  MyIntA
  MyIntB
  SomeTextValue
```

The queries always look like this:

```
Select  SomeTextValue from MyTable where MyIntA=1 and MyIntB=3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an index on `(MyIntA, MyIntB)`.

```
CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON MyTable (MyIntA, MyIntB);
```

Note: it might be preferable to make this pair of columns your primary key if the **pair of columns** (when considered together) contains only distinct values and there isn't another obvious choice for the primary key.

For example, if your table contains only data like this:

```
MyIntA  MyIntB
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
```

Here both `MyIntA` and `MyIntB` when considered separately are **not** unique so neither of these columns individually could be used as a primary key. However, the pair `(MyIntA, MyIntB)` **is** unique, so this pair of columns could be used as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The selectivity (number of discrete / distinct values) of the data in the columns MyIntA and MyIntB should assist you to decide on whether your index should be (MyIntA, MyIntB), (MyIntB, MyIntA), or just (MyIntA) or (MyIntB)

This [link](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Indexing_Strategies) should help, albeit for a different RDBMS